# Is there a way to reset body for next handler in vert.x?

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

I'm trying to implement a reverse proxy in quarkus.
It uses vert.x-http-proxy and needs to examine the body.
According to [this vert.x-http-proxy issue](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-http-proxy/issues/26) I know that vert.x-http-proxy does not support using BodyHandler but in fact every time I consume body without BodyHandler the proxy gets stuck.

Is there any way to reset the body stream?
Any help appreciated.

I'v tried to implement MyHandler as ProxyInterceptor, as Handler but every time I consume the body proxy stuck.

```kotlin
    fun onStart(@Observes router: Router, vertx: Vertx) {
        val proxyClient: HttpClient = vertx.createHttpClient(HttpClientOptions().setTrustAll(false))

        val proxy: HttpProxy = HttpProxy.reverseProxy(proxyClient)
        proxy.origin(8888, "localhost")

        val proxy2: HttpProxy = HttpProxy.reverseProxy(proxyClient)
        proxy2.origin(8888, "localhost")

        router
            .route()
            .path("/authorized/*")
            .handler(MyHandler(valueExtractorService))
            .handler(ProxyHandler.create(proxy))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution using Interceptor:

```kotlin
    override fun handleProxyRequest(context: ProxyContext): Future<ProxyResponse> {
        val length = context.request().proxiedRequest().getHeader("Content-Length")?.toInt() ?: 0
        return if (length > 0) {
            context.request()
                .proxiedRequest()
                .resume()
                .body()
                .flatMap {
                    //Reset body 
                    context.request().body = Body.body(it)
                    //Rewrite uri to remove useless part
                    context.request().uri = context.request().uri.substringAfter("/authorize")
                    //Inspect body to check authorization
                    checkAuthorization(context, it)
                    context.sendRequest()
                }
                .onFailure {
                    context.request()
                        .proxiedRequest()
                        .response()
                        .setStatusCode(401)
                        .setStatusMessage(it.message).send()
                }
        } else {
            context.sendRequest()
        }
    }
```